# How can I include a parameter != "" in cosmos DB query using Java Script

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Here is my coding:

```
// Set Query
var queryInput = "SELECT r.customer FROM root r";

if (Code) {
    if (hasWhere) queryInput += " AND ";
    else {
        queryInput += " WHERE ";
        hasWhere = true;
    }        
    queryInput += "r.customer.locationCode = @Code";        

}   
queryInput += " ORDER BY r.customer.number";

// Set Query Parameters
var query = {
    query: queryInput,
    parameters: [
        { name: "@Code", value: Code }
    ]
};
```

The actual code I would like change  below is below

- Actual code: `queryInput += "r.customer.Code = @Code";`
- Required code: `queryInput += "r.customer.Code != """;`

That particular field when no value in DB it is stored as `""`.

Can you help me on this?
Thank You

Comment: Don't get your purpose.You mean you just want to add a filter to make sure that Code column is not `""`?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. Could you please explain why you simply can't replace the actual code with the required code? You would ofc need to escape the string like this `queryInput += "r.customer.Code != \"\"";` but it should work.